# How to solve this? (Argument of the complex number in complex plane)

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, complex-numbers, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let the $z \in C$ s.t. $|z-10i|= 6 $

$\newcommand{\Arg}{\operatorname{Arg}}$
Say the $\theta = \Arg(z)$

Find the maximum and minimum value of the $8\sin \theta + 6\cos \theta$

---

My trial)

Trying to solve by picture and graph, I considered $8i\sin \theta + 6\cos \theta$ instead of the $8\sin \theta + 6\cos \theta$

Then, locus of the  $8i \sin \theta + 6\cos \theta$ is the tangent line of the  circle $|z-10i|= 6 $
(Surely   $ {-4\over 3} \leq \tan \theta \leq {4 \over 3}  $ )

So the question is I can't figure out the next step.

P.s.)
The answer sheet said "it is clear that when the case $\cos \theta = \pm{3 \over 5}  $ is maximum and minimum"

But this word totally unclear for me. Why does that case have a max or min value?

Comment: "complex plain" (geography) $\to$ "complex plane" (mathematics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta).$

Thus, $$r^2\cos^2\theta+(r\sin\theta-10)^2=36$$ or
$$\sin\theta=\frac{r^2+64}{20r}\geq\frac{2\sqrt{64r^2}}{20r}=\frac{4}{5},$$ which gives
$$\arcsin\frac{4}{5}\leq\theta\leq\pi-\arcsin\frac{4}{5}.$$
Also, write $$8\sin\theta+6\cos\theta=10\sin\left(\theta+\arccos\frac{4}{5}\right).$$
Can you end it now?

Actually, I assumed that $0\leq\arg{z}<2\pi.$

I got $$2.8\leq8\sin\theta+6\cos\theta\leq10.$$

I used the following reasoning.

By C-S $$8\sin\theta+6\cos\theta\leq\sqrt{8^2+6^2)(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)}=10.$$
The equality occurs for $(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)||(4,3)$, which gives $\theta=\arctan\frac{4}{3}\in\left[\arcsin\frac{4}{5},\pi-\arcsin\frac{4}{5}\right]$, which says that we got a maximal value.

Also, $$f(x)=8\sin{x}+6\cos{x}=10\sin\left(x+\arccos\frac{4}{5}\right)$$ is a concave function on $\left[\arcsin\frac{4}{5},\pi-\arcsin\frac{4}{5}\right],$ which says
$$\min\limits_{\left[\arcsin\frac{4}{5},\pi-\arcsin\frac{4}{5}\right]}f=\min\left\{f\left(\arcsin\frac{4}{5}\right),f\left(\pi-\arcsin\frac{4}{5}\right)\right\}=f\left(\pi-\arcsin\frac{4}{5}\right)=2.8.$$

Comment: Could you suggest process that how you get the answer 2.8 and 10? Your answer is correct, But I don't know the next step after the 
$8\sin\theta+6\cos\theta=10\sin\left(\theta+\arccos\frac{4}{5}\right)$ ?

Comment: @se-hyuck yang I added something. See now.

Answer (score 2):

If you draw a diagram, then the equation describes a circle of radius $6$ centred at $10$ units above the origin. Thus, we have that $r\cos\theta$ ranges from $-6$ to $6$ and that $r\sin\theta$ ranges between the extremes of $4$ and $16,$ with $r=|z|$ ranging between $4$ and $16.$

Now if we set $\cos\theta=x$ and $\sin\theta=y,$ then it follows that the maximum and minimum of $x$ occur at one of the endpoints of $[-6/r,6/r],$ with $r$ being either of the extremes in turn, which can be checked manually. Do the same thing for $y.$ Then the problem is now that of finding the extreme values of $6x+8y$ over a certain rectangle defined by the extreme values of $x$ and $y$ calculated above. For example, we have that $x$ varies between $-3/2$ and $3/2.$ Similarly, you can work out the range of values of $y,$ and the extremes of the linear function $6x+8y$ will now occur at the endpoints of the intervals calculated.

Comment: Plus @Allawonder, thanks for answering my question. But the case (6,16) which is the case $6 +16i$ isn't on the circle. That is the exterior point of the circle. My question is the considering the point lie on the circle

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for pointing this omission out. Corrected.

Comment: @se-hyuckyang I have made some corrections to my answer.

Comment: You still get some strange results, $x=\cosθ$ has a range of $[-1,1]$ by the definition of the cosine, your larger range $[-1.5,1.5]$ does not provide new information.