# Find the maximum and minimum value of this function(trigonometry)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This is the problem that I've stuck.

(This is the extension of the my question that [How to solve this? (Argument of the complex number in complex plane)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3328700/how-to-solve-this-argument-of-the-complex-number-in-complex-plane))

Find the maximum value, $M$ and minimum value, $m$

$f(\theta) = 8 \sin  \theta + 6 \cos  \theta $ $s.t. \theta \in [0, \pi]$

(${4\over 5} \leq {\sin \theta}  {\leq 1}$, $- {3\over 5} \leq \cos \theta \leq {3\over 5} $)

---

$f(\theta) = 10\sin(\theta + \alpha)$ for $\cos \alpha = {4\over5}$

My attempts is just my thought. I'm tried various method, But Everytime I try it I've stuck. **Please give me some concrete solution**. :(

**My attmept 1)**

By the above equation, It is clear that $ - 10 \leq f(\theta) \leq 10$

But I Can't find the exact $\alpha$'s size.

So the Can't figure out the max or min of the $f(\theta) $.

There might be different cases. I present two example in picture.
[image]

**My attempt 2)** To find the critical point

Find the $\theta$ s.t. $f'(\theta) =0 $

Hence critical point is $\theta$ s.t. $tan \theta = {4 \over 3}$

But this is just local maximum(either local minimum), Not Sure the Max or min value of the $f(\theta)$

The answer is $m$ = $14 \over 5$, $M = 10$

Thanks.

Comment: Find the critical points.

Comment: Are you comfortable with calculus? Your tags say calculus and pre-calculus

Comment: A little bit. Did you mean the question is more related with the algebra-precalculus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write 
$$f(\theta)=\sqrt{64+36}\left(\frac{8}{10}\sin(\theta)+\frac{6}{10}\cos(\theta)\right)$$

Comment: could you give me some more hints?

Comment: Then there exists an angle $$\phi$$ such that $$\cos(\phi)=\frac{8}{10},\sin(\phi)=\frac{6}{10}$$ and you will have $$\sin(\phi+\theta)$$

Comment: I'll try it again As your  hints

Comment: Then we get $$|f(\theta)|\le 10$$

Comment: Thanks for your hint I tried it again. But Still Can't figure out it. So Would you suggest the more concrete process for me?

Comment: It is $$f(\theta)=10\sin(\phi +\theta)$$ where $$\sin(\phi)=\frac{6}{10}$$